# How to include random effect to ivreg model in R?

Tags: r, panel-data, instrumental-variables

I have an endogenous variable X with instrumental variable Z and want to predict outcome variable Y. For this I have longitudinal data with user_id. Currently my model is:

````r
ivreg(Y ~ X|Z, data, x=T)
``
what I would have with longitudinal study would be
```r
lmer(Y ~ X + Z + (1|user_id), data)
````

How can I include (1|user_id) into the ivreg model ? Is there any other approach in R?